# http://protofunc.com/jme/ media player, how to synchronize 2 time sliders (when manually moved)

Tags: media-player, html5-video, html5-audio

Help really needed about html5 players managed with http://protofunc.com/jme/

This provides quit cool api but maybe not enough for my needs. http://protofunc.com/jme/documentation/documentation-api.html

I have 2 players simultaneously (1 video, 1 audio for *audio description*)
I'm looking for a way to synchronize manuals moves of those playing position handle slider ***.timeline-slider .ui-slider-handle*** (forward/reverse playing position).

If the playing can be synchronized,
*example for play (same idea for pause)*

```
$(document).bind('play', function(e){
                            // $('video, audio').not(e.target).pause();
                            $('video, audio').not(e.target).play();
                        });
```

When manipulating one of the handles .ui-slider-handle,  it gets the ui-state-active too. So it should be possible to know wich one (audio or video) is touched and leaved and then managing the other one to reflect the time slide (forcing its position using ".currentTime(myvalue)".

I made many tries like this one  but it's processed all time, not only when moving the handles, so it's a performance issue:

```
  $('audio, video').bind('timechange', function(e, data){
newTime = data.time;
dnewTime = newTime - oldTime;// delta T (sec)
oldTime = newTime;
if (( dnewTime > 1) || (dnewTime < -1)) // handler has been moved widely delta time is big
{
$('video, audio').not(e.target).currentTime(newTime);
};
$('#jmeLog').html('newTime: '+ newTime + ' | dT: ' + dnewTime );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don t know anything about the protofunc player, but in html5 my code in the dark would be sth like

```
yourVideoPlayer.addEventListener('seeked', function(){
    synchronizeMyTwoElements( yourVideoPlayer.currentTime );
});

 yourAudioElement.addEventListener('seeked', function(){      //not sure if it's seeked or onchange -> u have to check
    synchronizeMyTwoElements( yourAudioElement.currentTime );
});

//...
function synchronizeMyTwoElements( seekToTime ){
     yourVideoPlayer.currentTime = seekToTime;
     yourAudioElement.currentTime = seekToTime;
}
```